# Passing an XML vector image between activities

Tags: java, android, xml, bundle, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to pass an icon from an icon selection page, back to my creation activity where I then update the image and object to be created.

I have tried a few different methods on a half dozen posts and none of them want to work. They are mostly using bitmaps and .pngs so i'm wondering if I have to do anything inherently different for a vector image .xml thats just sitting in my drawable folder. Or if this method just wont work for this file type.

Each method I have used with putExtra and every kind of getExtra(s) has told me that there is nothing there (bundle = null).

Icon Page code to return to the main activity with the vector image

```
    public void returnToMainActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(IconPage.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("image", R.drawable.icon_trash1_24);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Main activity code to resume activity and get the vector image
where tempTask is the object and iconButton is the image button

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        //get icon from icon page upon resume
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            int picture = bundle.getInt("image");
            iconButton.setImageResource(picture);
            tempTask.setIconId(picture);
        }
    }
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nz1CH.png)

I would prefer not to have to convert it to a bitmap to pass it, because i am using it as an int in my object and everywhere else in my app that works great. Is there a better way to pass a reference to an existing file between activities?

thanks!

Comment: If possible, I recommend passing as a URL or file location. Modern OSes are very good at caching file data

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you cannot send things back with the putExtra when resuming an activity... I dont know why this is, I thought the onResume() would fix this but apparently not. There is also an onNewIntent() that supposedly also corrects this but I couldn't get that working either. Same again for startActivityForResult() which has been deprecated...

Anyways, if you.. future human.. also have this problem I have solved it by saving the data i want as a part of a class in an arraylist of size 1. This is the tutorial I followed, I am using this code elsewhere already so I didnt have to change much, but it might be over the top if you're looking for a simple solution.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcliHGR3CHo